# How create horizontal brackets for variation between columns in ggplot2 above barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: "variation between weeks"]

The dataset is here:
week,session
week1,100
week2,120
week3,90
week4,180

And Graph code without brackets is here:

```
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x=week, y=session)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue")+
  geom_text(aes(label=session), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=3.5)+
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the function `ggpubr::stat_pvalue_manual` originally designed for significance bars testing two groups of data points:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~group, ~value,
  1, 100,
  2, 120,
  3, 90,
  4, 180,
)

bar_data <- tribble(
  ~group1, ~group2, ~label, ~y.position,
  1,2, "20%", 200,
  2,3, "-25%", 200,
  3,4, "200%", 200
)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(group, value)) +
    geom_col() +
    stat_pvalue_manual(bar_data, bracket.shorten = 0.1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Differences can also be automatically created e.g. using

```
bar_data <- 
  data %>%
  transmute(
    group1 = group,
    group2 = group + 1,
    diff = (lead(value) - value) / value,
    label = paste0(diff * 100, "%"),
    y.position = 200
   ) %>%
   filter(!is.na(diff))
```